# Jquery Short-Hand Code For a Long List of Same Function

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML structure like this below:

```
List
<ol id="years">
<li class="2011">2011</li>
<li class="2012">2012></li>
<li class="2013">2013></li>
</ol>

News:
<div class="news 2011">Some News here</div>
<div class="news 2012">Some News here</div>
<div class="news 2013">Some News here</div>
```

I am in need of a short-hand code of the code below(It works, but i want it to be automated, not manual):

```
$('.2011').click(function() {    
    $(".news").show().not('.2011').hide()
 return false;
        });

$('.2012').click(function() {    
    $(".news").show().not('.2012').hide()
 return false;
        });

$('.2013').click(function() {    
    $(".news").show().not('.2013').hide()
 return false;
        });
```

What i tried was:

```
for(i=2011; i<= 2020; i++){

$('.'+i+'').click(function() {    
    $(".news").show().not('.'+i+'').hide();
 return false;
        });
}
```

When i click on a li item, it just hides everything, so it is not the expected result.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#years li').click(function(){
    $('.news').show().not('.' + $(this).attr('class')).hide();
    return false;
});
```

A better way is probably storing the year in a data attribute, eg:

```
<ol id="years">
    <li class="2011" data-year="2011">2011</li>
    <li class="2012" data-year="2012">2012></li>
    <li class="2013" data-year="2013">2013></li>
</ol>
```

Then going:

```
$('#years li').click(function(){
    $('.news').show().not('.' + $(this).data('year')).hide();
    return false;
});
```

Then you avoid issues if you add other classes to the li items.